# Convert back to string a sorted, converted-to-int list using list comprehension

Tags: python

suppose we have a string (of people height) called `heights` like this:

```
"89\n169\n168\n176\n171\n180-"
```

I want to sort them, so my steps are:

1. Strip the unnecessary character
2. Split the '\n' delimiter, producing a list of string numbers
3. Convert each numbers into `int`
4. Sort the list
5. Convert each element of the list back to `str` again.

So what I've done is:

```
heights = sorted(int(height) for height in heights.strip(" -\n").split('\n'))
heights = str(height) for height in heights
```

It's work actually, but the solution is a two-list-comprehesion and I think there's a solution with just one line only.

Comment: `b = sorted(a.replace('-', '').split('\n'))`

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey that sorts `"1000" < "200"`. Plus what if one of the numbers is negative? `strip` is safer here.

Comment: @ JON PANTAU, what is desired output.

Comment: `sorted(list(map(int, a.replace('-', '').split('\n'))))`

Answer (score 4):

I think the following should work:
It should return the string values but sort on the integer values. Sorted takes a key parameter which tells it to perform some function on the list elements and sort on that, in this case mapping them to an integer is all we need to do to sort in our desired order

```
heights = sorted(heights.strip(" -\n").split('\n'), key=int)
```

Comment: But now `[height for height in heights.strip(" -\n").split('\n')]` is just `heights.strip(" -\n").split('\n')`, the listcomp isn't buying us anything.  Also `key=lambda x: int(x)` is simply `key=int`, wrapping the function call in another function doesn't change anything.  (If the target function were more complicated than `int`, we might need a wrapper, of course, but here we don't seem to.)

Answer (score 0):

if final output is required in list of strings

```
list(map(str,sorted(map(int,heights.rstrip('-').split()))))
```

Comment: `list()` cast inside `sorted()` is not necessary. You could do without.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [str(j) for j in sorted([int((i.rstrip('-'))) for i in h.split('\n')])]
```

Comment: Should use strip carefully. Try output with negatives `heights='169\n-168\n176\n171\n180-'`

Comment: @mad_ yeah was going off OP example good point, could use `r.strip()` and would avoid that issue

Comment: @mad_ fixed, now should only remove that hyphen if it is unnecessary and trailing integer, not representing negative